# Best method of storing rapid inbound XML over UDP

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, udp

I am porting an old score display application from VBNet WinForms to C#.
This application takes incoming UDP data which is in a pseudo XML format and displays it nicely on a screen for people to watch.

The data is structured as follows

```
<Stands>
<Event>On</Event>
<ST>10</ST>                         
<Extra>Off</Extra>
<Stand1>                    //there are six competitor stands in total
    <SC>3</SC>              //progress
    <Name>Whareamu Whittaker</Name>     //competitors name
    <Loc>Masterton</Loc>            //competitors home town
    <Flag>New_Zealand.png</Flag>        //flag to display
    <BP>3.26</BP>               //one category of points
    <TP>3.14</TP>               //another category of points
    <PP>8.13</PP>               //the last category of points
    <Total>32.342</Total>           //total points
    <Colour>000000</Colour>         //color to display
</Stand1>
<Stand2>
    <SC>2</SC>
    <Name>Tim 3</Name>
    <Loc>Wallongong</Loc>
    <Flag>New_Zealand.png</Flag>
    <BP>9.36</BP>
    <PP>7.23</PP>
    <TP>3.74</TP>
    <Total>38.999</Total>
    <Colour>000000</Colour>
</Stand2>
<Stand3>....</Stand3>
<Stand4>....</Stand4>
<Stand5>....</Stand5>
<Stand6>....</Stand6>
```

Unfortunately I have no control over the format of the data, it comes in on a UDP broadcast and does not have proper XML headers etc, it literally looks exactly like the snippet above.

I receive this data, and make it look pretty on a screen.
The program is linked to the events vision mixer and displays the score on a screen depending on which camera is live.

Here is an example of how I display it...
[image: One of the display Screens showing a single competitor]

The data comes in once per second over the network, I must receive the data and display it, for a couple of the screens I also have to order the competitors based on who currently has the lowest point score.

Most of the programming is pretty straight forward, but I have a philosophical / best practice question around how to store all this incoming data.

When I built this in VB, I stored the data two ways, I manually parsed the XML and stored every value for every stand in a separate Variable. This was pretty horrible.
Then I also created a DataSet and DataTable and copied another set of the data into this which I used for quickly re-ranking the competitors and displaying on a "Totals Screen".

I'd like to receive the data in over the network and store it in a single place where I can rank and also display on the other screens without too much difficulty.
Because ALL of the data changes once per second, it needs to be an extremely fast and efficient way of doing it that also allows a re-rank once per second.

I'd be interested in how you would all approach this from a best practice point of view. How would you store this type of data?
I'm relatively new to C# coming from a VBnet winforms background. I could just copy what I did over there, but I already know its not a very nice solution so if I am going to the trouble of re-writing it in C# I should do it properly.